# Git staging deleted files automatically

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm working with Android Studio. When I create a new file or when I delete a file this change is automatically staged by git. How can I prevent this to happen? I want to make all changes effective only when I decide to stage and commit.

Comment: Yeah. Super annoying, right? AS has a bunch of annoying behaviors.